# Disable Fabric JS brush

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a simple stamp tool, which places a translucent geometrical shape like star, hexagon on mouse down, moves it on mouse move from its center and places it fully opaque on mouse up. But, it is giving me a trail of pencil brush on mouse move, no matter what. I do not need this pencil stroke. How can this be disabled ?

I have tried to set the width of freeDrawingBrush to 0 and now the stroke does not stay on the canvas, but it still shows during mouse move when the stamp shape is moving and then goes away on mouse up. Is there a way to disable this ?

I have also tried to disable freeDrawingMode but then disabling canvas wide selection of objects does not work, and hence I need a way to somehow stop the pencil brush when the stamp tool is selected.

Comment: I was able to fix this by adding "selectable:false" to every geometrical shape. I wonder why canvas's global selection property has no effect though!